# Loading Markers on Google Maps api v3 with MySql

Tags: mysql, google-maps-api-3

I followed [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3) of google to save markers on a database.
So, the tutorial teach me how to save on the database, it worked fine, etc.

But I want to load this values on the map, because it only save the values of the markers on database, but don't load them on a map.

This is my HTML if someone want to make a load marker(); example for me, or show me a link of a load marker example will be very helpfull, because I don't know SQL and PHP, and not so much HTML. I'm learning Thanks =)

> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
> <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> var marker;
> var infowindow;
>
> function initialize() {
>   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
>   var options = {
>     zoom: 13,
>     center: latlng,
>     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
>   }
>   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
>   var html = "<table>" +
>              "<tr><td>Name:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
>              "<tr><td>Address:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address'/></td> </tr>" +
>              "<tr><td>Type:</td> <td><select id='type'>" +
>              "<option value='bar' SELECTED>bar</option>" +
>              "<option value='restaurant'>restaurant</option>" +
>              "</select> </td></tr>" +
>              "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close'   onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";
> infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
>  content: html
> });
>
> google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
>     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>       position: event.latLng,
>       map: map
>     });
>     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
>       infowindow.open(map, marker);
>     });
> });
> }
>
> function saveData() {
>   var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
>   var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
>   var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
>   var latlng = marker.getPosition();
>
>   var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
>             "&type=" + type + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
>   downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
>     if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
>       infowindow.close();
>       document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
>     }
>   });
> }
>
> function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
>   var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
>       new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
>       new XMLHttpRequest;
>
>   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
>     if (request.readyState == 4) {
>       request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
>       callback(request.responseText, request.status);
>     }
>   };
>
>   request.open('GET', url, true);
>   request.send(null);
> }
>
> function doNothing() {}
> </script>   </head>
> ```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 is the companion article and shows getting data out of the database and on to the map.

Comment: But the ajax example can be used on my that don't use ajax ?

Comment: Why not read the article? (And your existing `downloadUrl()` function does use `XMLHttpRequest`, so AJAX would appear to be possible)

Comment: Tried to add some functions of "load()" but still dont working

Comment: Used the "phpsqlajax" that Andrew Leach sent to me and it works ! Thanks, topic can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 is the companion article and shows getting data out of the database and on to the map.

Comment: Now I'm gettin an error...stoped work and I just cleaned the table >>This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: Correction: DONT COPY the  phpsqlajax_genxml.php from the main page of google example, it's with problem, click on the link of google and copy de full code, it will work =)